# Can't browse computer via nlb cluster name

Tags: windows-xp, nlb, share

I have a fileserver nlb cluster, currently set to single affinity, made up of 2 2008R2 servers.  We switched the primary node today.  Now our Windows XP workstations can't browse to the cluster name (i.e. \fileserver) but can browse to the cluster ip address (i.e. \192.168.1.1) and can browse the member server by name (i.e. \filesvr1).  I remember having a similar issue when we had to change a registry setting to allow Windows XP boxes to see another file server that was in a failover cluster but had to be referred to by another name (\thisfileserver instead of \fileserver).  Convoluted, for sure, but it helped to prevent any  code changes from happening.

Well all of the programmers have their code on \fileserver and we can't have them switch their links every time \filesvr1 supercedes \filesvr2 or vice versa.  I can't remember that registry setting that allowed the file server to ignore that it's being called by the wrong name.  HELP!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308/en-us) is what you are looking for. The reg key tells the file server to accept connections when a different name is specified.

Why are you using NLB?  Why not use DFS to handle the replication and the directing of clients to the correct server?

Comment: THANK YOU! That was exactly it. I knew it was in lanmanserver somewhere.

Comment: No problem.  Don't forget to mark an answer as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/281308

Remember, you have no data replication with NLB or control over hwo changes what on the nodes

Comment: We pause DFSR during the code update and restart it after everything is confirmed up and running again.  Slightly inelegant but it works for us for now.